# Date Conversion in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing issue in date conversion in snowflake

```
Tab1 : Date(DD-MM-YYYYY) Col1 : 03-10-2018
Tab2 : Date(YYYY-MM-DD)  Col2 : 2018-10-03
```

I need to join

```
Tab1.Col1=Tab2.Col1
```

I am getting error as

`Date '03-10-2018' is not recognized.`

How to convert this date into 'YYYY-MM-DD' Please advise.

I have tried with all format :

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(Date(DOS, 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
Date((DOS, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_Varchar(Date(DOS, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

All above mentioned formula facing the same error :

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand this part of your question if datatype of your columns tab1.col1 and tab2.col2 is date: Date(DD-MM-YYYYY) and Date(YYYY-MM-DD)

Date is date, it does not have any formats when it is saved. You apply formats when you insert dates in text format to tell in which format the given value is, or when you select the date and want to output it in some specific format.

This works with date-type columns, joining is done without any formatting functions:

```
    create table tab1 (col1 date);
    
    create table tab2 (col2 date);
    
    insert into tab1 (col1) values ( to_date('03-10-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') );
    
    insert into tab2 (col2) values ( to_date('2018-10-03','yyyy-mm-dd') );
    
    select *
    from tab1, tab2
    where Tab1.Col1=Tab2.Col2;
```

Comment: Already the data is inserted in below mentioned format in 
Tab1.Col1 :03-10-2018 in this format ,
Tab2.Col1 :2018-10-03 in this format        

When i run the below query i am facing the format issue :
Date '03-10-2018' is not recognized.

select *
    from tab1, tab2
    where Tab1.Col1=Tab2.Col1;

Please advise.

Comment: What is the datatype of those columns Tab1.Col1 and Tab2.Col1 ?

Comment: The issue got resolved.

Comment: Can you explain how you resolved it, so that others can also learn from it, please?